# Unable to cast object of type '<>f__AnonymousType5`6

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, linq

I have two list. from one i want two select few data and then save that data to another list.

```
var ikj = Model.EmployeeInformationList
     .Select(m => new { m.GEmployeeGenInfoID, m.strDesignationName, m.strEmpOldCardNo, m.StrEmpID, m.GFactoryID, m.StrEmpName })
    .Distinct().ToList();


List<HolidayAlwEmployeeInfo> targetList = new List<HolidayAlwEmployeeInfo>(ikj.Cast<HolidayAlwEmployeeInfo>());

Model.HolidayAlwEmployeeInfoList = targetList;
```

but I'm getting this error

> Unable to cast object of type
>   '<>f__AnonymousType5`6[System.Guid,System.String,System.String,System.String,System.Guid,System.String]'
>   to type 'FactoryProduct.Entities.Payroll.HolidayAlwEmployeeInfo'

Comment: You need to use `.Select(m => new HolidayAlwEmployeeInfo() { someProperty = m.GEmployeeGenInfoID, otherProperty = m.strDesignationName, ... etc. }` - you have not posted you models so cant give you exact syntax

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You are trying to cast instance of anonymous type that you created by calling `new { m.GEmployeeGenInfoID, m.strDesignationName, m.strEmpOldCardNo, m.StrEmpID, m.GFactoryID, m.StrEmpName }` to the type `HolidayAlwEmployeeInfo`, you can't do that.

Rather, you need to rewrite the first line like this:

```
var ikj = Model.EmployeeInformationList
               .Select(m => new HolidayAlwEmployeeInfo(
                                m.GEmployeeGenInfoID,
                                m.strDesignationName,
                                m.strEmpOldCardNo,
                                m.StrEmpID,
                                m.GFactoryID,
                                m.StrEmpName ))
               .Distinct()
               .ToList();
```

and  make sure that `HolidayAlwEmployeeInfo` class has appropriate constructor to take all of the parameters `m.GEmployeeGenInfoID`, `m.strDesignationName`, `m.strEmpOldCardNo`, `m.StrEmpID`, `m.GFactoryID`, `m.StrEmpName`

Alternatively (as  Stephen Muecke mentioned in his comment), you can instantiate `HolidayAlwEmployeeInfo` with a simple constructor and assign properties/fields in the initializer, like this:

```
var ikj = Model.EmployeeInformationList
               .Select(m => new HolidayAlwEmployeeInfo()
                            {
                                GEmployeeGenInfoID=m.GEmployeeGenInfoID,
                                strDesignationName=m.strDesignationName,
                                strEmpOldCardNo=m.strEmpOldCardNo,
                                StrEmpID=m.StrEmpID,
                                GFactoryID=m.GFactoryID,
                                StrEmpName=m.StrEmpName
                            })
               .Distinct()
               .ToList();
```

Comment: You don't need a constructor with such a long parameter list. Use the object initializer syntax instead `new HolidayAlwEmployeeInfo { GEmployeeGenInfoID = m.GEmployeeGenInfoID ... }`

Comment: @chomba, constructor may be preferred if the class HolidayAlwEmployeeInfo has readonly fields and/or properties that are assigned in this statement

Comment: Sure but that was never mentioned by the OP.

Answer (score 1):

Set specific type instead of anonymous type and then casting:

```
var targetList = Model.EmployeeInformationList
                      .Select(m => new HolidayAlwEmployeeInfo {
                          GEmployeeGenInfoID= m.GEmployeeGenInfoID,
                          strDesignationName= m.strDesignationName,
                          strEmpOldCardNo= m.strEmpOldCardNo,
                          StrEmpID= m.StrEmpID,
                          GFactoryID= m.GFactoryID,
                          StrEmpName = m.StrEmpName })
                      .Distinct()
                      .ToList();
```